# How to get GraphQL Variables on postman

Tags: graphql, postman, postman-testcase

Lets suppose in request body, I am using following GraphQL Variables:

```
{
  "getUsers": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 5,
    "cursor": ""
  }
}
```

Now on test body, I want to get value of `limit`, how can I do that?

Comment: This should be a help, [GraphQL](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/graphql/)

Comment: Can you expand on the information here and share screenshots of what you have in front of you. What do you mean you want to _get_ the value of `limit` - to do what with it?